# How to display other fields with a foreign key on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 foreign keys: `client_id`, `vehicle_type` and `vehicle_make`. All 3 keys have corresponding in their respective tables, `clients`, `vehicle_types` and `vehicle_makes`. The primary keys in the tables are id, id and id respectively. I have stored the integer values in the child tables and i want to draw respective full descriptions of the fields in my tabular view.

```
        @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->plate_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->client->full_name }}</td> ///Problematic Code Block
            <td>{{ $vehicle->vehicle_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->year }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->make }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->model }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->color }}</td>
            {{-- <td>
                <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicle->id) }}">View</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('vehicles.edit', $vehicle->id) }}">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('vehicles.destroy', $vehicle->id) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td> --}}
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? You've added `// Problematic Code Block`, but you haven't described what the actual problem is... Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75891296/edit) to clearly indicate the issues with your existing code, including any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->plate_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client = App\Models\Client::find($vehicle->client_id)->full_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle_type = App\Models\Vehicle_type::find($vehicle->vehicle_type)->type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->year }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle_make = App\Models\Vehicle_make::find($vehicle->vehicle_make)->make }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->model }}</td>
            <td>{{ $vehicle->color }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('vehicles.show', $vehicle->plate_number) }}">View</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('vehicles.edit', $vehicle->plate_number) }}">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('vehicles.destroy', $vehicle->plate_number) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: You do not want to do that; you should never do queries directly in your view, it breaks the MVC architecture that Laravel is based on. Read up on Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships; you should be able to do `$vehicle->client->full_name`, `$vehicle->type->name`, and `$vehicle->make->make`, etc. when defined properly.